# Get pod wise resource consumption in Prometheus

Tags: prometheus, grafana

I want to display metrics in the following format using promql/Prometheus & Grafana.

[image]

I can think of below queries, but that gives me memory and cpu usage by a pod in every namespace but I'm looking to get the data in the above format(table shared) for a pod per namespace wise.

```
sum(container_memory_usage_bytes{container!=""}) by (namespace, pod)
        
sum(rate(container_cpu_usage_seconds_total{}[1m])) by (pod_name, namespace)
    
sum(container_memory_working_set_bytes{namespace="$namespace", container!="", image!=""}) by (pod)
```